# Determine tournament brackets with only the match results

Tags: combinatorics

I have a large database set, consisting of tournaments and the matches that make up each tournament. However, the tournament logic (i.e. the location of each match in the tournament bracket) in this database is unreliable, and I would like to recalculate them.

More specifically, given a set of matchpairs, each pair with one winner and one loser, is it possible to order these matches into a proper bracket, from first round all the way to finals? Note that these tournaments are almost exclusively double-bracket tournaments - players have to lose twice before they are out. This obviously complicates the problem somewhat.

And if this is not (definitively) possible, is there some mathematical proof that shows that there is only one correct possible configuration for a tournament bracket? Because in that case I will probably have to bruteforce it.

Edit: The rules of double-tournament brackets are as follows:

- Players start and progress in a regular (‘winners’) bracket. This bracket is the same as a normal tournament; winners move on to the next round until there is one winner left.
- When a player loses a match in the winners bracket, he moves to a special ‘losers’ bracket. In this bracket, he continues playing other losers (ie other players that have lost a match in winners), until he loses again, at which point he is eliminated.
- The loser’s bracket is different from a regular bracket, because every odd round a group of new players comes in from the winner’s bracket.
- Players progress in the loser’s bracket until there is one winner left. With one player in loser’s bracket and one player in winner’s bracket left, the two remaining players play a grand final to determine the winner of the bracket.
- In this grand finals, the player from the loser’s bracket has to win two matches before he is declared the winner, whule the player from the winner’s bracket only has to win once.

For a 32-player tournament, the loser’s bracket would go like this:

- The first loser’s round contains 16 losers. They play each other and 8 players move on to the second loser’s round.
- In the second loser’s round, 8 more players come in from the second winner’s round, for a total of 16 players. They play each other and 8 players move on.
- These 8 players play each other and 4 players move on.
- The 4 players are joined with 4 players comig from the 3rd round of the winner’s bracket. They play each other and 4 players move on.
- These 4 players play each other and 2 players move on.
- The 2 players are joined by 2 players coming from winner’s and play each other. 2 players move on.
- The 2 players play each other, 1 moves on.
- the remaining player battles the 1 player coming from winner’s. The winner of this match moves on to grand finals.

Comment: Can you post exact rules for the double-bracket tournaments?

Comment: Added rules, hope this is clear enough

Comment: Yes. Thanks. kind of a off-topic question: on which competitions do you have that schedule? For a long time I think that is a quite interesting competition format, yet I have never seen for real, as much as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a full reply, just thinking out loud, out of experience of watching several kinds of tournaments, not any deep mathematical analysis:

For **single elimination** tournaments it should be possible to reconstruct. Pick the player with only wins and that is the winner. Pick the player who only lost to that one, you have the other finalist, and have found the final match. Move on backwards - pick players with only wins except on matches with the previous players - and you should get them all. (assuming your data is complete, including "weird" stuff as players quitting, matches with "administrative" results different from the result on the field, and so on)

For **"complex" tournaments** in general, you can not be sure to reconstruct. Mostly because there may be repeated matches. An example, at the [European Football Championship 2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Euro_2004), Portugal and Greece played twice. Greece won both matches, 2-1 and 1-0. You may reconstruct the whole tournament but you can not know which match is from the group stage, which is the final.

**Double-bracket tournaments** will probably depend on the exact rules. For starters, may a couple of teams play each other twice? If they may, you may have the same problem as in the previous case.

Edit:
Given the set of rules in the updated question, the Double-bracket tournament has the same problem as the general "complex" tournaments I wrote about earlier. Two teams may meat both at the winners bracket and, later on, at the losers bracket; if the same team wins both times you can not say which match is from which bracket.

So, in general you can not be sure to reconstruct the schedule. Still, most of the times teams do not meat each other more than once, so most times it should be possible to reconstruct the schedule.<sup>[citation needed] :-)</sup> Also, you do not need to reconstruct the whole schedule, you "only" need to check consistency of the data, which should be possible even more often (but probably harder, because there may be several hypothesis to check)

This is an intuitive answer, with only minimal rigorous reasoning, from someone that has a similar problem (I have a large match database with some inaccurate tournament data, and some day I wish I'll check for consistency and data gaps). A more rigorous reply would be quite interesting.

Comment: I understand - and expect - no upvotes, as this is not an answer, only thoughts towards an answer. But I can not figure why the downvote. Could you tell me?